# Right to left when I send email

Tags: vb.net, email

I have Windows application send email to the customer, everything work perfect but the problem the email arrived in the left side. How I can make it right to left?

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim iphost As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostByName(Dns.GetHostName())
    Dim Emailmessage As New MailMessage()

    Emailmessage.From = New MailAddress("myemail@live.com")
    Emailmessage.To.Add("mailto@live.com")
    Emailmessage.Subject = "NOOR Phone - مشترك جديد"
    Emailmessage.Body = ("اسم المشترك :" & TextBox1.Text & vbNewLine & "تاريخ التسجيل :" & DateTimePicker1.Text & vbNewLine & "         الهاتف :        " & TextBox3.Text & vbNewLine & "الشركة : " & ComboBox1.Text & vbNewLine & "الدفع الشهري : " & TextBox4.Text & vbNewLine & "رقم الشريحة : " & TextBox5.Text & "")
    Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("smtp.live.com")
    smtp.Port = 587
    smtp.EnableSsl = True
    smtp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemail@live.com", "password")
    smtp.Send(Emailmessage)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question but I would like to give my own answer since I encountered this recently.
In the following paragraph:

```
Emailmessage.Body = ("<div style='direction:rtl'>اسم المشترك :" & TextBox1.Text & vbNewLine & "تاريخ التسجيل :" & DateTimePicker1.Text & vbNewLine & "         الهاتف :        " & TextBox3.Text & vbNewLine & "الشركة : " & ComboBox1.Text & vbNewLine & "الدفع الشهري : " & TextBox4.Text & vbNewLine & "رقم الشريحة : " & TextBox5.Text & "</div>")
```

change the `<div style='direction:rtl'>`
to: `<div dir=RTL>`.

It can also work as : `<p dir=RTL>`

(don't forget to close the paragraph  at the end)

Here is the solution that worked for me in my own project:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();                    
message.Subject = string.Format($"{model.MessageSubject}");                    
message.From = new MailAddress(model.MessageFrom);
message.To.Add(new MailAddress(model.MessageTo));
message.Body = string.Format($"<p dir=RTL>{model.MessageBody}</p>");
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

If you send a fake mail to your own address and open with i.e. Microsoft Outlook, the message will be displayed from right to left as it should. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your mail body inside a div with right to left direction:

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim iphost As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostByName(Dns.GetHostName())
    Dim Emailmessage As New MailMessage()

    Emailmessage.From = New MailAddress("myemail@live.com")
    Emailmessage.To.Add("mailto@live.com")
    Emailmessage.Subject = "NOOR Phone - مشترك جديد"
    Emailmessage.Body = ("<div style='direction:rtl'>اسم المشترك :" & TextBox1.Text & vbNewLine & "تاريخ التسجيل :" & DateTimePicker1.Text & vbNewLine & "         الهاتف :        " & TextBox3.Text & vbNewLine & "الشركة : " & ComboBox1.Text & vbNewLine & "الدفع الشهري : " & TextBox4.Text & vbNewLine & "رقم الشريحة : " & TextBox5.Text & "</div>")
    Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("smtp.live.com")
    smtp.Port = 587
    smtp.EnableSsl = True
    smtp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemail@live.com", "password")
    smtp.Send(Emailmessage)
End Sub
```

Comment: how can i do this ?? @Ali Sheikhpour

Comment: in line starting by **Emailmessage.Body** I have already added this **<div style='direction:rtl'>** . also at the end of this line don't forget **</div>**

Comment: not working :(
the application read the <div style='direction:rtl'> as string @Ali Sheikhpour

Answer (score 2):

as Rabeea Qabaha say, you can write this:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage()    
message.Body = ("<div style='direction:rtl'>"+ mail.Body + "</div>");
```

but dont forget in addition to set this line:

```
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

else this will show like a string.